# Python Implementation of Slepian Deguid algorithm for rearrangeble non-blocking network topologies

Tags: c++, python-3.x, algorithm, charts

I am currently working on implementing the Slepian-Deguid algorithm in Python and have encountered some challenges. I would appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to implement the Slepian-Deguid algorithm in Python. Specifically, I am looking for code snippets, explanations of key concepts, or recommendations for existing libraries that may include this algorithm. So far, I have reviewed academic papers and documentation related to the Slepian-Deguid algorithm, but the available resources are often theoretical and lack practical implementation details. I have also explored relevant Python libraries such as NumPy and SciPy, but I couldn't find direct support for the Slepian-Deguid algorithm.